# ¿Como puedo ingresar numeros de un txt y guardarlos en un array?

Tags: java, array, netbeans, archivo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es mi programa que estoy realizando pero necesito que los numeros vengan de un archivo txt]

Comment: Échale un vistazo a esta clase, es la que se ocupa del acceso a ficheros y a operar con ellos: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo de muchas formas, pero quizás la más sencilla sería usando IOUtils de la siguiente forma:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(RUTA_FICHERO);
String data = IOUtils.toString(fis, ENCODING);
```

También puedes usar FileUtils:

```
String data = FileUtils.readLines(FICHERO, ENCODING);
```

Con Java 8 puedes usar Streams (ejemplo que pinta cada linea que lee por pantalla):

```
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(RUTA_FICHERO))) {

        stream.forEach(System.out::println);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente tienes que tener clara cuál es la estructura del fichero que vas a leer y si se encuentra codificado. Si el fichero txt lo rellenas tu, te recomiendo utilizar RandomAccessFile, es bastante intuitiva.
Otra cosa deberías al inicio del fichero escribir una variable que determinará la cantidad de elementos que estarán contenidos en el fichero, eso evitaría excepciones innecesarias. Te presento el código de cómo podrías hacerlo utilizando esa estructura, si no quieres utilizarla puedes manejar con una excepción cuando el Reader llegue al final del fichero.

```
        RandomAccessFile rand = new RandomAccessFile("fichero.txt", "r"); //especificar la ruta del fichero
        int cant_elementos = rand.readInt(); //leer la cantidad de elementos que se encontrarán en el fichero. Esta linea puede ser eliminada si este elemento no existe
        double[] array = new double[cant_elementos];
        //lectura de los elementos y almacenamiento en un array
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = rand.readDouble();
        }
        rand.close(); //cierre del flujo
```